# Is it possible to get an existing DbContext in EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-patterns

I need to abstract transaction from data layer.
In business layer I want to do:

```
IModify modification = modification.Get();
using (ITransaction transaction = Transaction.Get())
{
    try
    {
        modification.Modify(); //do some changes
        transaction.Commit();  
    }
    catch 
    {
        transaction.Rollback();
    }
}
```

In data-layer:

```
public class EFDBModification : IModify
{
     public void Modify()
     { 
         using(var context = new MyDbContext())
         {
             // work with entities
             context.SaveChanges();
         }
     }
}
```

For old approach (TransactionScope) maybe implementation of ITransaction should be like this:

```
public class EFTransaction : ITransaction
{
    private TransactionScope _scope = new TransactionScope();

    public void Commit()
    { 
        _scope.Complete();
    }

    public void Rollback()
    { 
    }

    public Dispose()
    {
        _scope.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Now it is recommended to use Database.BeginTransaction() to start the transaction. Probably ITransaction implementation should be:

```
public class EFTransaction : ITransaction
{ 
    private MyDbContext _context = new MyDbContext();
    private Transaction _transactionContext;    

    public EFTransaction()
    {
        _transactionContext = _context.Database.BeginTransaction();
    }

    //implementation of interface
}
```

How should I transfer DbContext instance from transaction to EFDBModification object? I thought about the implementation of context as a singleton for a thread or for a webrequest but not sure about this. Or in some other way get existing DbContext. I dont want to pass it as argument to Modify() method.

Comment: "Now it is recommended to use Database.BeginTransaction() to start the transaction." where did you hear that reccomendation? `TransactionScope` works fine with EF.

Comment: I too would use Database.BeginTransaction. However, I am not sure why you are using it in this manner. I use transactions silently in my SaveChanges method to avoid having to use excessive try catch approaches elsewhere.

Comment: EF uses transactions internally to submit changes so you only need to create your own transaction if you want to do multiple SaveChanges() or combine SaveChanges with other operations on the same database.

Comment: "EF uses transactions internally" - If I want to use specific IsolationLevel?

Comment: "where did you hear that reccomendation?" -http://vunvulearadu.blogspot.com/2014/07/entity-framework-ef-transactionscope-vs.html